# regarding a piece of code

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to understand this piece of code as i m a beginner.Mostly these red color fonts. they are taking which page value?

```
$(function() {
        $("#title").blur(function() { QuestionSuggestions(); });    
});

function QuestionSuggestions() {
    var s = $("#title").val();            
    if (s.length > 2 && !($("#title").hasClass('edit-field-overlayed'))) {
         document.title = s + " - Stack Overflow";
         $("#question-suggestions").load("/search/titles?like=" + escape(s));
    }
}
```

Comment: 2 suggestions for improvement, it can just be `$("#title").blur(QuestionSuggestions);` and don't use `encode()`, use `encodeURIComponent()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function QuestionSuggestions() {
        var s = $("#title").val(); // Here we take the value of element with ID "title"   
        // If the length of the title is bigger than 2 or 
        // the element doesn't have 'edit-field-overlayed' class      
        if (s.length > 2 && !($("#title").hasClass('edit-field-overlayed'))) {
            // we set the title of the document as <title>[our old title] - Stack Overflow</title>
            document.title = s + " - Stack Overflow";

            // Load data from the server and place the returned HTML into the matched element.
            $("#question-suggestions").load("/search/titles?like=" + escape(s));
        }
    }
```

If you element with id title has longer title than 2, lets say "My title" and there is no class "edit-field-overlayed" we change the page title to "My title - Stack Overflow" and load html/text in element "#question-suggestions" by querying the URL http://yoursite.tld/search/titles?like=My%20title

Answer (score 1):

This looks like jQuery code. The expression `$("#title")` is a call to the jQuery `$` function. It looks for the HTML tag with `id="title"` and wraps a utility object around it. `.blur` is a method of that utility object, which supplies a function to be called when the mouse moves off the corresponding element.

The best thing would be to get stuck into a jQuery tutorial like [this one](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aGetting_Started_with_jQuery).

Answer (score 1):

The peice of code posted, condensed to a sentence is

"When the field with id 'title' blurs, execute an ajax query passing the content of that field as a parameter"