# Create a query suggestion page based on keywords

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery

I have an asp.net page and am writing some words in a question textbox named `txtTitle`. After moving to another txtbox named `txtbox2`, I want to open a question-suggestion page based on the keyword typed in `txtbox1` in the space before `txtbox2`. I've tried this but it is not working. Can anyone help?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
    $("#txtTitle").blur(function() { QuestionSuggestions(); });
    });

    function QuestionSuggestions() {
        var s = $("#txtTitle").val();
        if (s.length > 2) {
            document.title = s + " - ABC";
            $("#questionsuggestions").load("QuestionList.aspx?title=" + escape(s));
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Are you really just copying and pasting code from another SO thread and then asking someone do your work for you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4022894/regarding-a-piece-of-code

What have you tried? What errors are you getting? How is it "not working"?

You should at least demonstrate that you're making an attempt to solve this for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Create a WebService WebMethod in ASP.Net/C# that loads the suggestions. Your code in the WebMethod will load the datatable with the suggestions. In your WebMethod, return the DataTable as a hashtable, and it will automatically be converted to a JSON object.

```
   public Suggestions<Hashtable> GetSuggestion()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        List<Hashtable> ht = new List<Hashtable>();
        string q = Context.Request.QueryString["Q"];
        dt = [code to load datatable]
        ht = MethodToConvertToHashTable(dt);
        dt.Dispose();
        return ht;
    }
```

In your txtTitle.blur function, call question suggestions, which does a jQuery AJAX call to the webmethod (I left out the obvious).

```
function QuestionSuggestions() {
    var s = $("#txtTitle").val();
    var myJSON = $.ajax({
        url: '/directory/svc/yourwebservicepage.asmx/GetSuggestion?Q=' + s,
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function (msg) {
                    var d = msg.d; //THIS IS YOUR JSON OBJECT
        }
    }
}
```